# Deploy packer images on bare metal server?

Tags: vagrant, bare-metal, packer

How can I match my dev and production bare metal box?

The hosting provider does not allow or have a process to install custom images and only provides a selection from all the latest popular distributions.

KVM is available but they charge extra per usage and the engineer monitors the custom image installation from start to finish. So it's not the quick and repeatable process that is needed for fast deployment and iteration cycles using packer.

Comment: Use a proper configuration management system. Ansible, saltstack, puppet, chef, etc.

Comment: So, I would need to use the same base image that is used by the hosting provider in this case.

Comment: You don't really have a choice, right? But yes, use a vanilla image of your choosing and then apply your configurations to it using whatever CM product you prefer.

Comment: Also use a proper hosting provider.